# Show that $\int_{a}^{b}f''(x)f(x)\,dx\le1$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given:
$f$ is a function with a continuous second derivative;
$a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $f(a)f'(a)=f(b)f'(b)+1$.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting $0=0$.

Let $u=f(x), du=f'(x)\,dx, dv=f''(x)\,dx, v=f'(x)$
$$\int_a^b f(x)f''(x)\,dx
=f(x)f'(x)-\int_a^b f'(x)f'(x) \, dx$$
Applying integration by parts again to second part
$$\int_a^b f(x)f''(x) \, dx = f(x)f '(x)-f(x)f '(x)+ 
\int_a^b f(x)f''(x) \, dx$$
$$\int_a^b f(x)f''(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)f''(x)\,dx$$
$$0=0\text{?}$$

Comment: First of all, it would be nice if you type all math expressions in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). That would greatly improve readability of your expressions. Second, maybe it is a typo or not, but wouldn't it be $ f(b)f'(b）= f(a)f'(a) + 1 $ instead?

Comment: The first term in your first integration should be $f(b) f'(b) - f(a) f'(a)$, not "$f(x)f'(x)$."

Comment: I think you're nearly there, just remember that the $uv$ bit in your integration by parts needs to be evaluated from $a$ to $b.$ Now, what does $(f'(x))^2 \geq 0$ tell you?

Answer (score 4):

$\require{cancel}$
\begin{align}
& \xcancel{\int_a^b f(x)f''(x)\,dx
=f(x)f'(x)-\int_a^b f'(x)f'(x) \, dx} \\[10pt]
& \int_a^b f(x)f''(x)\,dx
= \Bigg[ f(x)f'(x)\Bigg]_a^b-\int_a^b f'(x)f'(x) \, dx
\end{align}

Comment: +1 for that "crossing without words." ;)